# chromedriver full screen doesn't work on Linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to start Chrome browser in full screen mode (similar to using F11) on Ubuntu 12.04. I am using the following code, but this doesn't see to work:

```
       if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            //Set full screen mode (similar to F11)
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-fullscreen");
            //Create a new Chrome Driver
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./lib/chromedriver");
            this.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
```

I am using Chrome version 34 with WebDriver version 2.41. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint 16, Chrome version 34.0.1847.132, Selenium 2.41.
Full screen mode works fine.
Try to use:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

to maximize browser window.

**Edited.**

Also you can try to run chrome in kiosk mode:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--kiosk");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This works fine in Linux with Chrome 34.

Or try to press F11 like:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

But for me it works fine only in Firefox.

Comment: this only maximizes the window, but I am trying to get it into a full screen mode where the tabs and address bar are hidden.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The '--kiosk' did the trick! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send F11 to the browser, you can probably do it this way:

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).SendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the following, but it didn't work: driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);